# Django as front end for Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, saas

Is it possible to setup a Django website, that will give the front end users accsses to run pre-coded script for Selenium automation under the hood? by default as headless browser. Each with his own cookies, dashboard, proxies for relevant accounts ect. I've seen some basic GUI which people have created with Python libararies, and the final outcome seems quite incomplete for an actual produect. On top of that, it seems a lot harder to create a SaaS app that fits for Windows, Linux, Firefox, Chrome ect rather than on the website server.

Comment: It's not clear to me where do you want selenium to run? If it's server side then Django just runs selenium commands on the server, the only problem is server resources for running a lot of browser instances. If it's on client side, then how do you get people to install selenium on their side?

Comment: I think that for less complicated application, it will be better to run the Selenium app on the server side and show the front end as Django dashboard, if it is actually possible. What will need for that as it goes for hosting? A server that can provide an virtual machine for each account? If it is on the client side, I could make installation pack with the relevant gecko or chrome driver. In that case, will Diango be a good choice for local GUI?

Comment: Server side I would probably go for some sort of docker or k8s setup. But if you wanna start small scale then just install selenium on server and do some sort of `subprocess.popen` to run a selenium script. Or use selenium's python bindings and wrap them in a celery job. You can use django dashboard to control all of this. Client side I'm not sure how to set this up.